# Simple code running on google colab but not working on kaggle

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory, mnist, kaggle

I am new to machine learning and trying to run following code

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml

mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)

mnist.keys()
```

its working fine on google colab but not working on kaggle. Does anyone know why it not working on kaggle notebook?

Answer (score 1):

This code is running fine on Kaggle. It takes some time but will complete.

Check again

output:

dict_keys(['data', 'target', 'frame', 'categories', 'feature_names', 'target_names', 'DESCR', 'details', 'url'])

Comment: Its weird, i am still getting following error:


gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1318                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1319                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1320             except OSError as err: # timeout error

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

Comment: below please find my notebook

https://www.kaggle.com/umairzubairy/mnist-beginner/

Comment: i figure out what is issue was with my code, i had to enable settings --> internet to ON, it was OFF ... thanks for your time for looking into it ....